# After iOS 7 update pathForResource: returns nil

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

Yesterday I updated to the newest iOS version and discovered that a crucial piece of my code fails to work properly.

```
// file is @"2/3/3-bottom-cen.png"
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:file 
                                                         ofType:nil
                                                    inDirectory:@"VillageImages"];
```

This code results in nil value for filePath and it happens *only* on iOS7 - the code works correctly on previous versions. I searched and failed to find any recent related problems so I'm asking here for any directions.

Comment: Does `pathForResource:@"3-bottom-cen.png" ... inDirectory:@"VillageImages/2/3"` work better?

Comment: For some reason it does. I was just editing my post with this information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found out that apparently you can't include path information in the first argument for `pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:` anymore, just the file name.

i.e. 'working' syntax for iOS7 would be

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3-bottom-cen.png" 
                                                         ofType:nil
                                                    inDirectory:@"VillageImages/2/3"];
```

Comment: Thanks, had the same issue, not sure why it doesn't state that in the documentation